# How to split a data in a single column to multiple columns and also removing special characters associated with it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My data looks like this:

[image]

I need the output to be like this:

[image]

how to clean this data?

Comment: please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do
    A = list.split(", ")
and/or
    A = list.split(" ")
to split the list wherever there is ", " or " " respectively

if by "special characters" you mean the commas they are getting removed with split(", "). if you mean the line chenges you can do
    A = list.strip().split(", ")